# Feasibility of a chemistry experiment involving combustion vegetable oil and fuel

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-chemistry

As a part of a chemistry experiment I would like to see the effect on the enthalpy of combustion of a mixture of vegetable oil and gasoline/diesel fuel when its percentage composition is changed (i.e 90% vegetable oil, 10 % fuel, and then 80% vegetable oil, 20% fuel etc.).

I am a bit confused about whether to use gasoline or diesel fuel with vegetable oil. I researched this and usually found that waste vegetable oil is used with diesel fuel for combustion in diesel engine cars. I will also be using straight vegetable oil. Is this fine?

I am also confused as to how I should conduct the experiment, what should I use to burn the fuels ( a spirit burner) or would this not be sufficient. I am thinking about using a spirit burner and placing the mixture with the spirit burner below a stand with a metal calorimeter with a certain volume of water. Taking the initial mass of the mixture and temperature of the water, I would then light the spirit burner up and wait for the maximum temp. of water to be reached and record it and then measure the final mass of the spirit burner. I would then repeat this process with a different percentage composition and calculate the enthalpy change each time.

Is this experiment is doable? What other materials might I need?

Answer (score 1):

Note that vegetable oil based diesel fuels do not use the original oil as mixture of esters of glycerol and fatty acids, but mostly [methyl esters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatty_acid_methyl_ester) of these acids. The methyl esters are prepared by trans-esterification by methanol, using sodium hydroxide as an alkaline catalyzer, with glycerol as a side product. This  way is the plant-origin fuel closer in composition and properties to mineral-based diesel fuels, compared to the original oil.

$$\ce{CH2(-O-CO-R)-CH(-O-CO-R)-CH2(-O-CO-R) + 3 CH3OH \\->[NaOH] 3 R-CO-O-CH3 + CH2(OH)-CH(OH)-CH2(OH)}$$

where $\ce{R}$ are generally different alkyl or alkenyl chains.

The carbon chain length in these esters ( typically $\ce{C14}$ or $\ce{C16}$) is much closer to diesel fuel  than to gasoline, so do their physical properties like volatility and specific energy or energy density.

Some oil burning devices or similar is preferred, as spirit burners expect high volatility at relatively low temperature. They usually burn previously evaporated spirit vapour, like if they were gas burners ( e.g. portable outdoor spirit burners ).

But you probably mean a low power,school grade, wick based spirit burner, that should be applicable for the oil as well. But even here, preferred may be wick burners for scented oils or similar. Or their wicks at least, as they may potentially better address lower viscosity and hydrophobic property of oils.

Little preparation experiments beat everything else.

Note that low power wick burners have  high heat dissipation due long time of burning, that may affect measurement.

---

**A comment to the comment**:

I have not expected you would make any synthesis, just making aware the plant based diesel oil is not really the plant oil. I have already expressed the concern gasoline is too different to both diesel fuel and edible oil.

I suppose the school burner may be good, but I have concerns rather about the calorimetric measurement itself.

- There will be needed enough oxygen. Either you burn just a little, or you need big calorimeter, or calorimeter with pressured air.
- A school spirit burner may be too heavy and contains a lot of fuel and stuff.
- Be aware the difference between the mineral diesel fuel and edible oil will be minimal.

We can simplify the burning by the equation:

$$\ce{CH2 + 3/2O2 -> CO2 + H2O}$$

For $\pu{14 g}$ of fuel ( $\ce{-CH2^{}-}$ ) is needed $\pu{48 g}$ of oxygen ( 3/2 $\ce{O2}$). $\pu{1 L}$ of air with oxygen partial pressure $\pu{p \simeq 21000 kPa}$ and $25 ^{\circ}C$ has oxygen density $\rho=\dfrac {pM}{RT} \simeq \pu{0.271 g/L}$.

Stuff has generally [trouble to burn below 16% of oxygen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limiting_oxygen_concentration), so consider rather about 5 times less oxygen than there really is: $\pu{\dfrac{0.271}{5} g/L} \simeq \pu{0.054 g/L}$.

So $\pu{1 g}$ of fuel (diesel, edible oil ) would need $\dfrac {\pu{\dfrac {48}{14} g}}{\pu{0.054 g/L}} \simeq \pu{64 L}$ of air.

With pressuring, the needed volume of calorimeter is much smaller because of higher percentage of oxygen depletion.

About the temperature measurement procedure itself:

- Measure temperature at regular intervals also some time before and some time after the action to get a priori and a posteriori temperature trends.
- Draw the temperature versus time plot.
- Extend both respective a priori and a posteriori trend lines across the "action time interval".
- Note the time with the half step of the temperature rise.
- Note the temperature difference of both trend lines at this time.
- The difference is your measured warming up of the calorimeter.

Comment: Be cautious not to burn Diesel oil in an open basin or bowl. When cold, diesel fuel does not burn like alcohol lit by a match. It needs a wick, and then it burns around the wick like a candle. But suddenly as the temperature gets high enough, the whole liquid suddenly catches fire. This can be dangerous. Take care !

Comment: @Maurice He already plans to use a wick based spirit burner, frequent in school in my young days. So it would be rather like scented oil esoteric burner, just not so well scented.

Answer (score 1):

This is, I'm sorry, a pointless experiment. If you know the composition, and the enthapies of the components, you can perfectly predict the result.

I can only see one motivation to do it: You have made a home-built calorimeter that is quite a lot better than people would expect, and want to demonstrate that.

Your proposed calorimeter will however loose a lot of heat to the outside, also produce smoke and char, and probably in a different way for all your different fuels.

Not gonna work, sorry.